# Show that $ || (\Delta f)(\mathbf p) ||$ is the maximum of the directional derivatives or all unit vectors at $\mathbf p$.

Tags: differential-geometry

If $f$ is a differentiable function on $ \Bbb{R}^3 $, show that the gradient $\Delta f = \sum \frac d{dx_i}U_i$ has the following properties>

a) $\mathbf v[f] = (df)(\mathbf v) = \mathbf v \cdot (\Delta f)(\mathbf p)$ for any tangent vector at $\mathbf p $.

b) The norm $ \| (\Delta f)(\mathbf p) \| = [\sum \frac {df}{dx_i}^2(\mathbf p)]^{1/2}$ of $ (\Delta f)(\mathbf p)$ is the maximum of the directional derivatives $\mathbf u[f]$ for all unit vectors at $\mathbf p$. Furthermore, if $ (\Delta f)(\mathbf p) \neq 0 $, the unit vector for which the maximum occurs is $\frac {(\Delta f)(\mathbf p)}{\| (\Delta f)(\mathbf p) \|}$

For a) we have that

$v_p \cdot  (\Delta f)(\mathbf p) = \sum \frac {df}{dx_i}U_i \cdot v_jU_j(p) = \sum \frac {df(p)}{dx_i}v_i = v_p[f]  $.

For b) I have no Idea. I was told that the lagrange multipliers should help, but, overall I am lost. The notation is really awful for me. I would appreciate a hint, but some "explanation" could be very helpful aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable at $p$ then there is a linear map $df(p):\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$ such that
$$f(p+X)-f(p)=df(p).X\ +o\bigl(|X|\bigr)\qquad(X\to0)\ .$$
This map $df(p)$ has an $(1\times n)$-matrix whose entries are the values $df(p).e_i={\partial f\over\partial x_i}(p)$. It follows that
$$df(p).X=\sum_{i=1}^n {\partial f\over\partial x_i}(p)\>X_i=\nabla f(p)\cdot X\ .$$
This is part (a) of your problem. For part (b) note that by definition and Schwarz' inequality we have
$$\|df(p)\|=\sup_{|X|=1}\bigl|df(p).X\bigr|\leq\bigl|\nabla f(p)\bigr|\ .\tag{1}$$
On the other hand, if $\nabla f(p)\ne0$, for the unit vector $$X:={\nabla f(p)\over\bigl|\nabla f(p)\bigr|}$$
we have $\bigl|df(p).X\bigr|=\bigl|\nabla f(p)\bigr|$. This proves that in fact $\|df(p)\|=\bigl|\nabla f(p)\bigr|$.